# how do I filter dataset based on "Version" column containing _________.000 decimal?

Tags: r, filter, decimal

I have a dataset where I am trying to filter based on 3 different columns.

I have the 2 columns that have character values figured out by doing:

`filter(TRANSACTION_TYPE != "ABC", CUSTOMER_CODE == "123")`

However, I have a "VERSION" column where there will be multiple versions for each customer which will then duplicate my $ amount.
I want to filter on only the VERSION that contains ".000" as decimal since the .000 represents the final and most accurate version. For example, VERSION can = 20220901.000 and 20220901.002, 20220901.003, etc.

[image: Version examples]

However the numbers before the decimal will always change so I can't filter on it to equal this 20220901 as it will change by day.

Comment: Is `VERSION` class `character` or `numeric`? If the former, then `filter(grepl("\\.000$", VERSION))` should work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Dar! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```r
quux <- data.frame(VERS_chr = c("20220901.000","20220901.002","20220901.000","20220901.002"),
                   VERS_num = c(20220901.000,20220901.002,20220901.000,20220901.002))
```

If `is.character(quux$VERSION)` is true in your data, then

```r
dplyr::filter(quux, grepl("\\.000$", VERS_chr))
#       VERS_chr VERS_num
# 1 20220901.000 20220901
# 2 20220901.000 20220901
```

Explanation:

- `"\\.000$"` matches the literal period `.` (it needs to be escaped since it's a regex reserved symbol) followed by three literal zeroes `000`, at the end of string (`$`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272 for more info on regex.

If it is false (and it is not a `factor`), then

```r
dplyr::filter(quux, abs(VERS_num %% 1) < 1e-3)
#       VERS_chr VERS_num
# 1 20220901.000 20220901
# 2 20220901.000 20220901
```

Explanation:

- `abs(.) < 1e-3` is defensive against high-precision tests of equality, where floating-point limitations (in computers in general) don't always see a number very-close to zero as exactly zero. See [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272), https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f.
- `. %% 1` is the modulus operator, reducing a number down to its fractional component.

Comment: I should've mentioned that it was a character value. The first suggestion and explanation worked. Thank you so much! I also made a note in regards to the images and posting the code and such for future reference / questions. I appreciate your help and feedback on how to be better myself!